# How to implement Dynamic Dictionary with joining of 2 dictionaries

Tags: c#, .net

**The query sounds confusing but really need your experts assistance on this, as I am not sure how to articulate this request any further **

I have a requirement to generate a CSV file based on following condition

1. Default parameters are defined and data has to be passed.

   - Project_Name
   - Project_ID
   - Start_Time
   - End_Time
2. User can define their own parameters (call it custom params)
3. User can add value to these custom params

For #1, in the implementation code, some parameter values can be passed which later will be reused during the construction of CSV file. But however for Start_Time and End_Time has to be passed as and when it happens, but making sure the other parameters has values.

For #2, the developer can add decide upon their own parameters, which means they can define their own parameters. This definition of parameters has to be done only ONCE and then for each of these parameters its respective values are added. This will be a repetitive process (which is nothing but #3 in the list)

Once the Step #2 and #3 is completed, we need to combine the headers and then respective data to be added accordingly to generate CSV file.

Now, how to go about creating this dynamic structure where definitions can be created once and multiple data can be added accordingly.

We are thinking of using Dictionary but not sure how to go about. Any assistance is highly appreciated.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: we tried using dictionary, but things became more static rather then dynamic.

Comment: @aioracle, can you please update your question to include examples of what you have tried. Maybe someone can spot where you went wrong.